# Item renderer for dynamic DataGrid

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have a problem with dynamic item renderer for data grids elements.
I'm initialiizng columns in my data grid dynamically, like this:

```
for each (var item in _collection)
{
    var i:MyClass= item as MyClass;
    var dgc:DataGridColumn = new DataGridColumn(i.Id.toString());
    dgc.headerText = i.Name;
    cols.push(dgc);
}
_myDataGrid.columns = cols;
```

To every cell I want to pass integer. When it has -1 value, cell should display specific text but when it's 0 or 1 it should contain checkbox.
Do you know how can I achieve that? I don't any ideas for now, despite I was thinking about this for quite long time. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Would probably help if you showed us what `MyClass` is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create itemRenderer with two states. One state with checkbox another with text